# ResponseText is null even though it should be set JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I have a big problem and I don't see any mistakes in my code.  The program should add two values from fields `p1` and `p2` and upload them to a site without reloading the whole page. I did it in simple javascript, but I would like to use AJAX. Everything is already done but there is minor bug somewhere.

I you look at the `validate()` and `insterter()`, the  alert has proper value

```
 alert("data = "+data);
 req.send(data);
```

but msg from insterter is just empty. I don't know why. Please help. I'd like to correct this code.

```
var msg = req.responseText;
        alert("msg = "+msg);
```

Why is the reason that msg is null?

---

```
@WebServlet("/Serwlet")
public class Serwlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
static String KOD =

"<html>"+
"<head>"+
 "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1250\">"+
"<title>Testowanie</title>"+
"<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"servletD2Script.js\"></script>"+
"</head>"+
"<body>"+
"<div id=\"msg1\">Pierwsza suma</div>"+
"<div id=\"msg2\">Pierwsza suma</div>"+
"<center><h2>Testowanie parametrów</h2></center>"+
"<hr>"+
"<form method=\"get\" action=\"Serwlet\">"+
"p1<input type=\"text\" size=\"50\" name=\"p1\" onblur=\"validate()\"><br>"+
"p2<input type=\"text\" size=\"50\" name=\"p2\" onblur=\"validate()\"><br>"+
"<br><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Wyślij formularz by GET\">"+
"</form>"+
"</hr>"+
"<hr>"+
"<form method=\"post\" action=\"Serwlet\">"+
"p3<input type=\"text\" size=\"50\" name=\"p3\" onblur=\"funkcja()\"><br>"+
"p4<input type=\"text\" size=\"50\" name=\"p4\" onblur=\"funkcja()\"><br>"+
"<br><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Wyślij formularz by POST\">"+
"</form>"+
"</hr>"+

"</body></html>";

public Serwlet() {
    super();

}
static boolean raz = true;
private void serviceRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

      response.setContentType("text/html");
      response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      if(raz){out.print(Serwlet.KOD);raz = false;}
      String name = request.getParameter("name");   // dostaję nazwisko
      String org = ""; //jakas wartosc 
      out.write(org != null ?  org : "");    // zwracam organizację lub pusty napis, jesli nie znam nazwiska
}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    serviceRequest( request, response);
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    serviceRequest( request, response);
}

}
```

---

```
var req;

function validate() {
//var idField = document.getElementById("name");
var wrt1 = document.getElementById("p1").value;
var wrt2 = document.getElementById("p2").value;
var data = eval(wrt1)+eval(wrt2)+"";

if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var url = "Serwlet";
req.open("POST", url, true);      
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
alert("data = "+data);
req.send(data);
req.onreadystatechange = inserter;
}




function inserter() {
if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
        var msg = req.responseText;
        alert("msg = "+msg);
        if (msg == "") {
            document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "<div style=\"color:red\">"+"MSG WAS EMPTY"+"</div>";
            //document.getElementById("msg1").value = "blabla";
        }
        else
            document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "<div style=\"color:red\">"+msg+"</div>";
            //document.getElementById("msg1").value = "COOOO JEST";
    }
}
}
```

---

THIS PART OF CODE IS ALWAYS INVOKED MSG IS ""

```
if (msg == "") {
        document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "<div style=\"color:red\">"+"MSG WAS EMPTY"+"</div>";
        //document.getElementById("msg1").value = "blabla";
    }
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as [tag:java]? Plus, you should show the code responsible for producing the reply message. Maybe it *is* empty?

Comment: Probably because the servlet returns an empty response. You should post the relevant part of your `"Serwlet"` class.

Comment: just a wild guess - shouldn't `onreadystatechange` event listener be assigned before you send the data, i.e. before the event?

Answer (score 0):

`raz` seems to be true only once, so next times you enter the servlet you don't enter in the if-statement and don't print `Serwlet.KOD`.

Then I don't understand that :

```
  String org = ""; //jakas wartosc 
  out.write(org != null ?  org : "")
```

It always print an empty string, it's useless.

Also it's a good practice to end the `serviceRequest` method with `out.close();`.

Comment: Changed it. It does not change anything the problem
is that var data(validator()) has value and msg(insterter) has not;/

Comment: What have you changed exactly? You removed `raz=false` in the if-statement?

Comment: And what are you expecting to do with `data` on the server? You don't even use it .And you should send it using `req.send("data="+data);`, then retrieve it with `request.getParameter("data")`

Comment: If I don't have this raz=false the site with be dubled(printWriter will write again the same thing at the bottom of the site).

Comment: req.send("data="+data);, then retrieve it with request.getParameter("data")
That works(the value appears on the site) but I have many bugs. Line 38. Object does not service particular method
http://wklej.org/id/756249/

Comment: `request.getParameter("data")` is for server side, on the javascript side you can't use `var msg = req.getParameter("data");`, Use `var msg = req.responseText;` to get the content you write in `out` (on server side).